# How to save Json Array to Java script array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON array. Which comes from api call, and I want to parse it in Javascript.

```
{"class_section":{"classess":["PG1","PG2"],"sections":{"PG1":["A","B"],"PG2":["A","B"]}}}
```

I want to save this to a Javascript array:

```
array calssess=["PG1","PG2"];
array sections["PG1"]=["A","B"];
array sections["PG2"]=["A","B"];
```

I tried below method:

```
        var res= xmlhttp.responseText;

        var jsonData = JSON.parse(res);

        for(var i = 0;i<jsonData.class_section.classess.length;i++){
                var class_to_add= jsonData.class_section.classess[i];

               var sections_to_store= jsonData.class_section.sections[i];
              }
```

`jsonData.class_section.classess[i]` gives correct answer required.

but `jsonData.class_section.sections[i]` gives as object type.

even `jsonData.class_section.sections.class_to_add` also gives object type.

but `jsonData.class_section.sections."PG1"` gives A,B., but I don't want to use hardcoded value like PG1 in sections. Because classes are unknown.

Can someone help?

Comment: PHP, Javascript, or something else? Which language?

Comment: How are you getting this "JSON Array"? JSON is a string format, by the way...

Comment: [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4935632)

Comment: It is data coming from api. And i want to parse in javascript.

   var res= xmlhttp.responseText;

   var jsonData = JSON.parse(res);

         for(var i = 0;i<jsonData.class_section.classess.length;i++){
                    var class_to_add= jsonData.class_section.classess[i];

                   var sections_to_store= jsonData.class_section.sections[i];
                  }

Comment: jsonData.class_section.classess[i] gives correct answer required.

but jsonData.class_section.sections[i] gives as object type.
even jsonData.class_section.sections.class_to_add also gives object type.
but jsonData.class_section.sections."PG1" gives A,B. But i dont want to use hardcoded value like PG1 in sections. Because classes are unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
var object = {"class_section":{"classess":["PG1","PG2"],"sections":{"PG1":["A","B"],"PG2":["A","B"]}}};


var classess = object.class_section.classess;
var sections = [];


sectionsArray = object.class_section.sections;

for(var index in sectionsArray) {
  sections[index] = sectionsArray[index];
}
```

At the end the `classess` and `sections` variables should have the desired values.